# Android emulator INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error

Tags: android, memory-leaks, emulation

I'm testing an app that i am building on the emulator. It works just fine a couple of times, but then it gives me a 'Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE' error and i have to wipe the emulator data.

I know that i could increase the emulator memory or set the install location:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andrewsmith.android.darkness"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

but i want to know if this means that my app has leaks?

Any (easy to use) tools out there that i could use to detect memory leaks or other issues?

Answer (score 0):

[I would suggest to use blustack as emulator , it worked for me grate](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I'll try it, but this doesn't exactly answer my question. I have a device to test this on, I wanted to know if this means my app is leaking memory.

Comment: oh, no i think it some times happens in emulator ..u will get answer on real device itself